# Making a random binary matrix with fixed probability of zeros

Tags: matlab, probability

I do not have the communications toolbox and do not want to pay for it so i can't use the `randsrc` function. The probability for the occurrence of a `0` should be 0.2 and the occurrence of a `1` thus 0.8.

```
x = rand(1 100)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A = rand(1,100); % uniform distributed between 0 and 1
B = A>=0.2; % Makes the lowest 20% values 0, the rest 1
```